# Suppose we are given a coin which lands heads with probability 1/4 (and tails with probability 3/4) each time it is flipped.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Suppose this coin is flipped exactly 12 times in a row. Let the random
variable X denote the total number of times that the coin comes up heads.
What is the expected value of X?

Comment: Seethe information about how to ask questions here.  In particular, do not just command us to do your work for you.

Comment: $\frac14\cdot12=3$.

Comment: @DonThousand could you explain why you multiplied it by 12? I thought the answer would be just 4.

Comment: I think you should study expected value more. Me simply telling you the answer to one problem won't help you long term.

Comment: Binomial experiment, 12 trials. The mean of a binomial distribution with probability $p$ is $np$.